# Cannot access var from another class in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I have initialized a ProgressBar in my MainActivity and assigned a view to it in onCreate. Inside my MainActivity I have created a WebViewClient class and I want to change the visibility of spinner inside it but for some reason I can't.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var myWebView: WebView
    lateinit var spinner: ProgressBar
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        spinner = findViewById(R.id.progressBar1)
        myWebView = findViewById(R.id.webview)

        myWebView.loadUrl("www.example.com")
        myWebView.webViewClient = MyWebViewClient()

        }
    private class MyWebViewClient : WebViewClient() {
        override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView, url: String?) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url)
            view.visibility = View.VISIBLE

            //Here I want to change the visibility of spinner
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide all warnings or errors encountered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use inner class instead of nested class if you want to access members of outer class. See: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/nested-classes.html.

In your example you should add `inner`:

```
private inner class MyWebViewClient : WebViewClient()
```

Be aware that it's easy to introduce a memory leak using inner classes, as every inner class contains a reference to outer class.

Comment: Thanks, it works. And sorry for the unclarity in code but it seems that you figured it out :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work, most likely the problem is in the `progressView` in `xml`, it is set to `match_parent` and just overlaps your `webView`. 
Try after `view.visibility = View.VISIBLE` add `spinner.visibility = View.GONE`